# Can't add strings in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const std::string exclam = "!";
    const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;
    std::cout << message;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code not work? Error returned:

```
error: invalid operands of types `const char[6]' and `const char[8]' to binary `operator+'
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers. This is my first time on the site and I am astonished at the number of elaborate explanations in such a short time interval.

Regarding the actual question. How come this works then:

```
const std::string hello = "Hello";
const std::string message = hello + ", world" + "!";
```

Is it because ", world" and afterwards "!" get concatenated with variable hello (which is defined)?

Comment: Why not do: 

const std::string message = "Hello, world" + exclam;

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Just FYI, if there's an answer that you like, make sure you accept it.  You're more likely to get help in the future.

Comment: To concatenate two const char*, remove the + operator, "Hello" ", World"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because in C++, string literals (like `"Hello"` are not of type `std::string`. They are plain char arrays, or C-style strings.

So for the line `const std::string message = "Hello" + ", world" + exclam;`,the types the compiler has to work with are:

`const std::string message = const char[6] + const char[8] + std::string;`

and given the associativity of `+`, the operations it has to perform are:

`const std::string message = ((const char[6] + const char[8]) + std::string);`

That is, the left-most addition must be evaluated first, and the result passed to the rightmost addition.

So the compiler tries to evaluate `const char[6] + const char[8]`.
There is no addition defined for arrays. Arrays are implicitly converted to pointers, but this doesn't help the compiler. That just means it ends up with `const char* + const char*`, and no addition is defined for pointers either.

At this point, it doesn't know that you want the result to be converted to a `std::string`.

However, in your second example:

```
const std::string hello = "Hello";
const std::string message = hello + ", world" + "!";
```

it works, because the operations the compiler would see were `std::string + const char[8] + const char[2]`. Here, the first addition can be converted to `std::string + const char*`, and here the addition operator *is* defined, and returns a `std::string`. So the compiler has successfully figured out the first addition, and since the result was a string, the second addition looks like this: `std::string + const char[2]`, and like before, this isn't possible, but the array can be converted to a pointer, and then the compiler is able to find an addition operator that works, again resulting in a `std::string`.

Answer (score 18):

```
"Hello" + ", world"
```

Since these are c-style strings, you cannot append them with +. You can append a std::string to a c-style string, but not 2 c-style strings this way, instead add a std::string() constructor around one of them to make a temporary, ie:

```
"Hello" + std::string(", world")
```

Comment: He could also just omit the `+` operator between `"Hello"` and `", world"` like:  
`const std::string message = "Hello" ", world" + exclam;`

This is also an acceptable way to concatenate string literals.

Answer (score 6):

C++ doesn't do many of the automatic 'behind the scenes' conversations of other OO languages.

As Doug said you need to do std::string("hello") + std::string(" world"), the language doesn't do this for you.

However you can do

```
std::cout << "hello" << "world" << exclam;
```

Because std::cout knows how to print a const char[] as well as a string

Answer (score 5):

String literals are simply zero terminated array of chars in C++.  There is no operator that allows you to add 2 arrays of chars in C++.

There is however a char array and std::string + operator.

Change to:

```
const std::string message = std::string("Hello") +", world" + exclam;
```

In some languages like Python string literals are equivalent to variables of type strings.  C++ is not such a language.

Answer (score 4):

In the line where you form your message, the entire expression to the right of the = is performed first, and only then it is assigned to a C++ string. At that point, your "Hello" and your ", World" are still C strings (const char[]) which is why you are getting an error. Addition goes from left to right, so the pair of the C strings is added before you attempt to add the combination to the std::string exclam.

You need to either cast them within the expression (e.g., std::string("Hello")), or create string variables for each like you did with Exclam.

Answer (score 3):

C-style string literals ("Hello" and ", world") are equivalent to anonymous arrays:

```
static const char anon1[6] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
static const char anon2[8] = { ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

...so when you type `"Hello" + ", world"`, you're trying to add two arrays `anon1 + anon2` which is not an operation that C or C++ supports.

Remember, string literals in C/C++ are just arrays (or addresses of arrays). You have to use a string class (e.g. `std:string`) in order to use operators like `+`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that basic string literals like `"this is a literal"` are not of type `std::string` so they do not concatenate with the `+` operator.

In post `C++14` you can use standard user defined string literals that **are** of type `std::string`:

```
using namespace std::literals; // somewhere in the scope

auto message = "Hello"s + ", world"s; // message is type std::string
```

See [std::literals::string_literals::operator""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s).